# ansible playbook : Error to connect to a windows host (winrm) using aws secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, winrm, aws-secrets-manager

i try to connect my ansible host to a windows server using winrm

my ansible version :

```
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Dec  5 2019, 15:45:45) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

it work when the password is in vars

```
 - hosts: win
  vars:
    ansible_user: "ansible"
    ansible_password: "Itismypassword"
```

and it is not working with this configuration :

```
- hosts: win
  vars:
    ansible_user: "ansible"
    ansible_password: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'ansible_password', bypath=true) | regex_search ('ansible_password\\\":\\\"(.*)\\\"','\\1')}}"
```

i retrieve the password ( i used a regex to get only the password, i'm not sure that is the correct way to do that)

when i want to use it i get this error:

```
fatal: [win_server]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid type for configuration option plugin_type: connection plugin: winrm setting: remote_password : Invalid type provided for \"string\": ['Itismypassword']"
}
```

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: `list[str]` != `str`; while I don't have an AWS Secret Manager to test against, thankfully the error message makes knowing the fix pretty obvious: grab the `| first` of the resulting list

```yaml
    ansible_password: "{{
      lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'ansible_password', bypath=true)
      | regex_search ('ansible_password\\\":\\\"(.*)\\\"','\\1')
      | first }}"
```

As for your aside, the answer is **for sure** not to use regex to extract those values; based on the regex you're using, I'm guessing the output of that `aws_secret` lookup is in fact JSON, and thus the correct behavior is to `| from_json` to turn it back into a `dict` (or `list[dict]`), then extract the key you want

*something like this, but without knowing the actual shape this is likely not 100% correct:*

```yaml
    ansible_password: >-
      {{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'ansible_password', bypath=true)
      | from_json | map(attribute='ansible_password') | first }}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to mdaniel i progress in my understanding of ansible and aws secret manager: it's working with regex but i try to figure out how to do it in a proper way...

when i get secret from aws secret manager with this commands :

```
debug: msg="{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'ansible_secret', bypath=true) | dict2items }} "
```

i have this answer :

```
"msg": [
        {
            "key": "ansible_secret",
            "value": "{\"password\":\"itismypassword\",\"user\":\"ansible_user\"}"
        }
    ]
```

i don't know how to get "itismypassword" from value field ><  a jquery maybe ?